# How can I find the fc-event div by having the event Object ID?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to append some additional html to the event divs depending on data I get from an ajax function.

I have grabbed all the eventobjects with

```
var array = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' );

for(var a=0; a<array.length; a++)
{
    $.post(site_url+"/calendar/get_workers_on_job", { 'id' : array[a].id },
       function(data) {
           for(var b=0;b<data.length;b++)
           {
             //Here I want to append the json data to the event div.
           }
        },'json');
}
```

But I can't figure out how to find out which event div is associated with it.

I'd very appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: How are your events being rendered? Through an event source? You can attach an `id` to an Event Object: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: The events are being redered with an ID. It's the ones I get with the cliendEvents function and later send in the post function as 'id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a class on the div then use jQuery.

Comment: I set the ID attribute of the div to the ID of the event Object. And now I can find it. 
Thanks.